# Почему не компилируются ассеты?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Настраиваю рабочий проект на новой машине. Команда

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

дает непонятную ошибку( вообще нужна при деплое)

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'geocoder'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Timeout
Did you mean?  Time
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder/exceptions.rb:32:in `<module:Geocoder>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder/exceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder.rb:5:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
NameError: uninitialized constant Timeout
Did you mean?  Time
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder/exceptions.rb:32:in `<module:Geocoder>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder/exceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder.rb:5:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bundler/gems/geocoder-54b45d106824/lib/geocoder.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/tiazar/rails_projects/3auto/pereezd-test/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/tiazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@testpereezd/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

На той же машине, где идет разработка сделал новый гемсет и ошибка повторяется. Со старым гемсетом все работает.

```
gem list geocoder

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

geocoder (1.2.9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае оказался виноват bundler версии 1.15.1, удалил, поставил принудительно версию 1.13.6. Работает как положено.